# How to open ViewController with launch screen?

Tags: xcode

Whenever I try to work with the launch screen and problem ViewController at the same time, I try to modify the custom name but it would not let me. The problem is that when I click on show the assistant editor this is what it looks like with the launch screen:

[image: image showing what opens when I click on show assistant editor]

Answer (score 1):

First thing to say here is that the launch screen will not run any code. It is there purely to make the initial screen look like the UI of your app. However, that UI HAS to be defined in interface builder.

You cannot change the background colour (for example) in code.

Any other view controller in your app will have code associated with it. If it does then using it as the launch screen is not going to work.

Because of this you should keep your launch screen storyboard completely separate from the working view controllers in your app.